# Nullable reference types C#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I am trying to use code from classes in a console program in classes for a forms program so our project can have a working GUI and that console program used nullable reference types.  how can i bypass this so i get the same functionality?

```
    static private Radio? _radio;
```

[image]
[solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvZYG.png)

Comment: If you don't mind and it works, you could click '✔' to mark the below reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have to update `.csproj` file to support C# 8.0 version and [enable nullable option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language#nullable),

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

---

**How to edit `.csproj` file?**

- Right click on GUI Version 1 project -> Click on Edit Project file -> Update file with above two tags -> Reload project.

[image]

Alternate way:

- Right click on GUI Version 1 project -> unload project -> Edit project File -> Update file -> Reload project.

[image]

<sub>**Note:** Image and GIF content is just for demo purpose, .csproj content will be different for you</sub>

Comment: where do i add it though? i added a picture of the solution explorer, when i open the .csproj it just opens where i last left off.

Comment: A quick way: right-click unload project, then double-click the project.

Comment: @RED, I updated my answer. Kindly look at it.

Comment: @RED If you are using the .net framework, double-click the app.config file and add the following code below </startup>: `<PropertyGroup>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
     </PropertyGroup>`